# How to open a popup with the total size of the screen of extended monitors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a scenary where two TVs are used as extended monitors in vertical to show an orders list. I am trying to open a popup that fill the whole size of the screen of the two monitors, but, even after setting the height as 3840px the popup only fills the first screen. Any suggestions?

```
function popitup(a) {window.open(a,'open_window','height=3840, left=1, location=no, menubar=no, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, status=no, titlebar=no, toolbar=no, top=1, width=1080,fullscreen=yes');}
```

The application itself uses java with spring mvc and thymeleaf for the front end. The code above in javascript is just to open the popup.

Comment: On a browser? You can't.

Comment: On a browser you can't even get the screen size if window is not maximized.

Comment: Is there anyway of doing it with jquery or any plugin?